# Assign XML highlighting to a file extension in gedit by default

Tags: gedit, syntax-highlighting

I am working on a new project that saves data in an XML format but does not use the XML file extension. As such, whenever I open the file in `gedit` I have to go and set the *manually* set the highlight mode (by going to by navigating to view -> highlight mode then scrolling right down to the end and selecting XML). I'd like to avoid doing this.

How can I convince `gedit` to apply the XML highlight to this file type/extension by default?